# How to access java object methods returned value in thymeleaf template

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Tried to get the returned value of the method in thymeleaf template but faced an issue. following is the environment

**Controller class :**

```
@Component
@Controller
public class HighController {
    
    
    @GetMapping("/abcdata")
    public String customerForm(Model model) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        
         
        model.addAttribute("abcdata", new CostDataModel());     
        
        return "abcdata";
    }

}
```

**getter and setter**

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Component
public class CostDataModel {
    
    public SubList abcdata;
    
}
```

**Main Class**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@ComponentScan
@SpringBootApplication
public class AbcmanagementApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CostmanagementApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**thymeleaf template view** (abcdata.html)

```
<div class="starter-template">
      
         <form action="#" th:action="@{/abcdata}" th:object="${abcdata}" method="post">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="subs">Choose subs</label>
                    <select class="form-control selectpicker" th:field="*{abcdata}" id="abcdata">
                        <option value="">Nothing selected</option>
                        <option th:each="abcdata : ${abcdata}"
                                th:value="${abcdata.abcdata}"
                                th:text="${abcdata}">abcdata
                        </option>

                    </select>
                </div>
             
         <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
    </form>
    </div>
```

**SubList class**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Component
public class SubList {
    
    @Autowired
    private RequestToken rt;
    
    public List<String> getSub() throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
       // some code here
    return list;
        
    }

}
```

I need to access the entire list returned by the `getSub()` method in the thymeleaf template. but instead of list, it is returning the entire object. In thymeleaf, I am using drop down field to populate entire list but some issue.

Comment: please suggest. I am stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved it. Instead of creating the new instance of `CostDataModel ()` and passing as model attribute , copied the entire method code of `getSub()` in the controller class. see below

```
@Controller
public class HighController {
    
    
    @GetMapping("/abcdata")
    public String customerForm(Model model) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // all the code of getSub() method 

        
         
        model.addAttribute("abcdata", abcdata);     
        
        return "abcdata";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Start by removing `@Component` from the objects that you put in the Model (so `CostDataModel` and `SubList`). This annotation means that you want the Spring container to create a single instance, but this is not want you want here.
2. Remove `@Component` from `HighController`. You already have `@Controller` which is enough to have Spring pick up the class as a singleton with component-scanning.
3. What is the use of `RequestToken` inside `SubList`? As `SubList` is not a Spring singleton anymore, the autowiring will not work. If you really need it, maybe pass it manually via the constructor.
4. With `th:object="${abcdata}"`, you select the `CostDataModel` instance in Thymeleaf. When you do `th:field="*{abcdata}"` in the `<select>`, it means that Thymeleaf will call the `getAbcData()` method on the selected `CostDataModel`, which returns the `SubList` instance. This is not what you want, you should use simple `String` field. It is a bit hard to guess what the exact solution is to your question, maybe you can use some better names than `abcdata` everywhere to better understand your question. In any case, you might want read about [Using HTML select options with Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/04/16/using-html-select-options-with-thymeleaf/) on my blog to understand more about this and then maybe update your question if things are still not working.

Comment: Yes, things are still not working. I referred your blog post though. I just want the syntax to get the list items from the method getSub() in thymeleaf.  this method is basically returns the subscriptions list from Azure. please suggest

Comment: If you need more help, please provide a reproducible example on GitHub for example.